# Why my description will result so many misunderstanding?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This is [my question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120342/how-to-extract-an-answer-on-mathematica-se-as-an-image) today.The original intention is I want to get the picture of certain answer or question by it [share link](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-07-10-00-39-16.png),then I can conveniently distribute it to my friends stumped in *Great Firewall*.From this [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120342/how-to-extract-an-answer-on-mathematica-se-as-an-image?noredirect=1#comment325907_120342),I get a [relative link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44099/web-browser-screen-shot) by .Then I know the useful function `dotNetBrowserScreenshot`.And I can get what I want by

```
dotNetBrowserScreenshot["https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95725/21532",He‌​ight->500]
```

But there are something I don't content where I should assign the value of the `He‌​ight`.So I give a edit to the original post.This is all what I do and my thinking.But why I get so many misunderstandings in the following comments?

Comment: BTW if you're trying to do this to bypass the Chinese national firewall... they don't block Stack Exchange sites. Some of the scripts loaded from googleapis.com are blocked, yes, but the site is still readable without them. (Albeit painstakingly slowly)